# The function "REVERSE" does not support the data type "DT_I4" for parameter number 1

Tags: visual-studio, variables, visual-studio-2015, ssis, expression

i'm trying to make an expression for one of my variables in visual studio and I get this error saying:

> The function "REVERSE" does not support the data type "DT_I4" for
>   parameter number 1. The type of the parameter could not be implicitly
>   cast into a compatible type for the function. To perform this
>   operation, the operand needs to be explicitly cast with a cast
>   operator.
>
> Evaluating function "REVERSE" failed with error code 0xC0047089.

And this is my code:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::FileName] , 1, REVERSE(FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName],"_", 1)))
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is pretty clear, you are doing a `REVERSE` of a `FINDSTRING`.

`REVERSE`'s parameter needs to be literal values and `FINDSTRING` returns an integer (`DT_I4`).

I believe you want to do it the other way arround, first `REVERSE` the string and then calculate the position of the underscore, so that the `SUBSTRING` can take characters up to that point:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::FileName] , 1, FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileName]),"_", 1))
```

---

**Edit**: Try this to retrieve the last part after the last `_`.

```
SUBSTRING(
    @[User::FileName], 
    LEN(@[User::FileName]) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileName]),"_", 1) + 2,
    LEN(@[User::FileName]) 
        - (LEN(@[User::FileName]) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileName]),"_", 1) + 2) 
        - FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileName]),".", 1) + 1)
```

Comment: I would like to get expression from the back of my string, before "_" symbol occur. The thing is that your code does not work.
Let's say the string is "Scan_Report_PL". I would like to get "PL", while your code gets me "Scan_Re"

Comment: @Rocket128 should have posted your example and your desired behaviour on your original post! I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, now it's working but it's also returning file extension. I mean those are .csv files, and now i'm getting "PL.csv" expression. That's why I was trying to start from the back of the sentence

Comment: @Rocket128 so why didn't you mention that you also had the extension in the first place?

Comment: I don't know, thought that you will follow my lead and start from the back of the sentence. Sorry for that and thank you so much for your help